# Set content-security-policy so that other sites could embed a specific pdf file in an iframe

Tags: iis, web-config, content-security-policy

On our IIS website, there is a PDF file that we need to allow other sites to show in an iframe.
Currently the content-security-policy in the web.config is this:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors 'self'" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>  
</system.webServer>
```

As this is a pdf file, I could not use meta tags for that.
As I could not find an answer to this anywhere, I tried to compromise and created another web.config in the subdirectory of the pdf file with:

```
        <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors '*'" />
```

trying thus to allow all the files in that directory to open in an iframe. However, IIS complained that I have multiple definitions of "Content-Security-Policy", so that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to add this custome header in subdirectory. All configuration only needs to be in the web.config of the root directory. And in my test, even if this header is not defined, the iframe  use cross-domain pdf file and the pdf can be displayed normally.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your comment. As I wrote, there is a web.config file in the root directory and I wrote how the content-security-policy is defined. When I try from another site to include a PDF (from "our" site) in an iframe, I get this in Chrome:
Refused to frame 'https://www.ericom.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self'".

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to compromise and created another web.config in the
> subdirectory of the pdf file with:
>
> ```
>     <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="frame-ancestors '*'" />
> ```
>
> trying thus to allow all the files in that directory to open in an
> iframe. However, IIS complained that I have multiple definitions of
> "Content-Security-Policy", so that didn't work.

It weird because in subfolders you can [override root web.config](https://port135.com/configure-iis-to-ignore-web-config-files-in-application-subfolders/).

Alternatively you can try [url-rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) to conditionally rewrite CSP header to another one as like [here](https://gist.github.com/ChrisFulstow/108bbf11cd08acb2bdef).

Note that [PDF can be embedded](https://csplite.com/csp/test352/#test) anyway using Google Drive or [PDF.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) regardless CSP.

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand your issue. Not only you need to delete the custom headers in web.config of subdirectory, but also change the value of Content-Security-Policy.

The content is prohibited from being displayed within an IFRAME due the Content Security Policy being set.Specifically they are setting the Content-Security-Policy tag to frame-ancestors 'self'. There is no way you'll be able to embed their pages into a page of your own using IFRAME when PDF and iframe are in different domain.

One way is do not use Content-Security-Policy. PDF will be loaded in iframe.

Another way is change the value. I set the value to **default-src 'self'** ***.trusted.com** . It worked.

[image]

Comment: I need to allow any other site to iframe the file, not just a known site. I also need to prevent other files on the website from being iframed (to prevent Cross-origin attacks)

Comment: You can set value to frame-src'self'.